# Get AngularJS to compile directive and link function before executing the controller

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Due to the nature of my program, I require functions to be placed on the scope and shared between the directive's link function and the controller, like so..

```
.controller("controller", function($scope, $location, $timeout, model) {

    //irrelevant code

    $scope.addObject(draggables[i]);

};


.directive("designCanvas", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, element) {

            $scope.addObject = function(draggable) {

                // irrelevant code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I make this function call I get '$scope.addObject is not a function'.

My problem is the controller is being executed before angularJS has evaluated the link function, because the function call works fine when I delay it by a few seconds using $timeout

So my question is, how can I get the contents of the link function to compile first?

Comment: Compilation depends upon the HTML graph (DOM). If the controller is defined over a parent of the directive, it would get instantiated before linking happens. Why can you not add the addObject to controller. Or check `if($scope.addObject) $scope.addObject(draggables[i]);`

Comment: Thanks for your time :) I'm using easelJS within the directive to manipulate the canvas and its variables are local to the link function so are unavailable for me to modify in the controller. I'm also trying to create some seperation and have a more structured MVC format.. if($scope.addObject) would work but doesn't quite fit my purpose as I will need the function to execute regardless

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing this function as a service and inject the service into the directive and controller. **Shared function** should be implemented as a service.

```
.factory("objectService",function(){
    return {
       addObject : function (draggable){
          //your code of this function
       }
    };
});

.controller("controller", function($scope, $location, $timeout, model,objectService) {

    //irrelevant code

    $scope.addObject = function (draggable){
        objectService.addObject(draggable); //reuse this function
       //objectService.addObject.call($scope,draggable) if you want to call this function with $scope as the context.
    };
};

.directive("designCanvas", function($timeout,objectService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, element) {
            $scope.addObject = function(draggable) {
                objectService.addObject(draggable); //reuse this function.
                //objectService.addObject.call($scope,draggable) if you want to call this function with $scope as the context.

                //write more logic specific to this function, like modifying link's local data.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) How would this work if I needed the addObject function to modify variables held within the link function?

Comment: @Tom Hadkiss: if that logic is only specific to the link function (controller does not have this logic) => this logic is not shared. You could write it below the line `objectService.addObject(draggable);`

Comment: @Tom Hadkiss: if the controller and the directive both have this same logic => this logic is shared, you could pass more parameters to the `objectService.addObject` and write your logic inside.

Comment: The method will only be modifying variables local to the link function so it's not shared. I'm confused what you mean by write it below the line? Write what exactly? Thanks again

Comment: @Tom Hadkiss: see my updated in the link function. Hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

I would create `$watch` in controller that listen on some flag in directive.

Something like:

```
.controller("controller", function($scope, $location, $timeout, model) {

    //irrelevant code
    $scope.flag = false; 

     $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.flag;
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue == true){
            $scope.addObject(draggables[i]);
         }
    }, true);


};


.directive("designCanvas", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, element) {
            $scope.flag = true;
            $scope.addObject = function(draggable) {

                // irrelevant code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit messy but I think this is a direction. Instead `$scope.flag` you can try use callback like:

```
 .controller("controller", function($scope, $location, $timeout, model) {

     $scope.callback= function() {
       $scope.addObject(draggables[i]);
     }
    };

.directive("designCanvas", function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function($scope, element) {

                $scope.addObject = function(draggable) {

                  // ....

                  $scope.callback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help,

Answer (score 0):

I would create another directive and make it depend on `designCanvas`:

```
.directive("designCanvas", function() {
    return {
        controller: function() {
            this.addObject = function(draggable) {
                alert(draggable.name);
            }
        }
    }
})

.directive("draggable", function() {
    return {
        require: '^designCanvas',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, designCanvasController) {
            designCanvasController.addObject(scope.item);
        }
    }
});
```

Usage something like this:

```
<div design-canvas>
    <div ng-repeat="item in draggables" draggable>{{item.name}}</div>     
</div>
```

#### Demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0ffp5uJMsLoYnT4Ry3z?p=preview).

Tying directive to controller is not the best idea, I think. You should either go with service or one more directive.